# store staggered output from chrome console into single variable and copy it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, screen-scraping

Below is the code to scrape data from a particular site using tag and id name:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div #menu a").forEach((item)=>(fetch(item.href).then(res => res.text()).then(data => console.log(data))));
```

Here menu is id name of div tag of anchor tag, item returns all the filtered anchor tags that i want to store locally.

I want to return the output in single `var "data"` but the output i am getting is in staggered manner like one url entirely then its showing to copy that code and then next same thing for another url and so on

Comment: Use this: data = await Promise.all($$('div #menu a').map(async a=>(await fetch(a.href)).text()))

Comment: i know async is better but it gives me lots of promises and i dont want that i just want to scape the webpages and store it in single var... can u suggest me how it can be done @Nitesh Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to download the file u can use console.save from below
I used this code to scrape different documentation sites and other course contents and many more by changing the tags and ids

http://bgrins.github.io/devtools-snippets/#console-save

```js
(function(console) {
    console.save = function(data, filename){
        if(!data) {
            console.error('Console.save: No data')
            return;
        }
        if(!filename) filename = 'console.html'
        if(typeof data === "object"){
            data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4)
        }
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/json'}),
            e    = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
            a    = document.createElement('a')

        a.download = filename
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        a.dataset.downloadurl =  ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':')
        e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
        a.dispatchEvent(e)
    }
})(console)
document.querySelectorAll("div #menu a").forEach((item)=>(fetch(item.href).then(res => res.text()).then(data => add(data)
)));
var body;
var add = data => {body += data;}
console.log(body)
```

just use "console.save(yourObjectHere)" to download and last 3 lines of code does the merging, for copying the data to another variable use " copy(yourObjectHere) "